# Just can't get my IPN to work with multiple items

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

the IPN works for putting the order details in, etc. But I'm trying to get the item_numbers back to MySQL table.. and I can't see where I'm going wrong. And I can't work out how to log my _POSTs. I'm guessing it's just not finding any item_numbers...but I can't get the _POST variables to see what exactly's coming in.

```
$oID = $_POST['txn_id']; // joins o and oItems
  $n = 1;
  while (TRUE) 
    {
    if (isset(${"_POST['item_number" . $n . "']"}))
        {$item_numbers[] = ${"_POST['item_number" . $n . "']"};}
    else {break;}
    $n++;
    }
  $n = 1;
  foreach ($item_numbers as $key => $item_number)
    {

        $pID = $item_number;
        $pAmount_o = ${"_POST['mc_gross_" . $n . "']"};
        $pQuantity = ${"_POST['quantity" . $n+1 . "']"};
        $q = "INSERT INTO `oItems` (ID, pID, pAmount_o, oID, pQuantity) VALUES ('', '$pID', '$pAmount_o', '$oID', '$pQuantity')";
        mysqli_query($c, $q); 
        $n++;
        }
```

And I can't tell what's going on with this log either.. :(

```
$t = time();
$post = serialize(print_r($_POST));
$q = "INSERT INTO `ipnLogs` (`logID`, `logTime`, `logType`, `logContent`) VALUES ('', '$t', '_POST', '$post')";
mysqli_query($c, $q);
```

Comment: You can view POST variables by: <pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>

Comment: great well i'm logging the POST now, so hopefully I'll have it sorted out soon enough :)